# Manual numbering of tables

Tags: tables, numbering

I have a table like below and I would like to change its numbering by `\renewcommand\thetable{1S}`. However, I am not sure why it is not working. Could you please help?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lscape}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textheight}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt} % default: 6pt
\scriptsize
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{longtable}{@{} l | *{3}{lll|} lll| l | *{3}{lll|} lll @{}} % 26 columns in all
\caption{Comparison of solution approaches using theoretical instances (values are in average)}
\label{tab-theo1} \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Inst.} & 
\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\makecell{Mathematical \\ programming}}  & 
\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\makecell{NA-ACO \\ algorithm}}      & 
\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\makecell{Heuristic \\ algorithm}}   & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP1 \\ (\%)}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP2 \\ (\%)}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP3 \\ (\%)}} &
\multirow{3}{*}{Inst.} & 
\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\makecell{Mathematical \\ programming}}  & 
\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\makecell{NA-ACO \\ algorithm}}      & 
\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\makecell{Heuristic \\ algorithm}}   & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP1 \\ (\%)}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP2 \\ (\%)}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP3 \\ (\%)}} \\ 
\cline{2-10} \cline{15-23}
& HPI  & FS\#  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}  
& HPI  & FS\#  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}    
& HPI  & FS\#  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}    
&   &   &   & 
& HPI  & FS\#  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}  
& HPI  & FS\#  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}    
& HPI  & FS\#  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}    
&   &   &  \\ 
\hline

%% body of table
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
    1     & 1     & 10    & 0.85  & 1     & 10    & 0.03  & 1     & 10    & 0.13  & 0     & 0     & 0.3   & 34    & 0.87  & 10    & 7.6   & 0.79  & 10    & 11.73 & 0.97  & 10    & 0.29  & 12.4  & 20.6  & 2.3 \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use it?  Also, why are you trying to change the numbering in that way?  It'd be easier to change the counters instead.

Comment: I will have multiple tables and no problem if the numbering of all of them changes. I want the numbering starts with sth like 1S, 2S, 3S, .... That being said, I have no problem if we can change the counter to create a numbering like above.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load both `lscape` and `pdflscape`. No need to load `makecell` twice, or is there?

Comment: Before series of tables with your numbering: `\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}S}
` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before series of tables with your caption numbering insert:

```
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}S}
```

**Off-topic:**
See, if use of `tabularray` package and rotating some column headers is acceptable to you. Using them, the table can have bigger fonts and will become like this:

[image]

Dummy text above table is only for comparison of table width and size of fonts used in table. MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}   % new
\usepackage{makecell}   
\usepackage{tabularray} % new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[66]

\begingroup
\setcounter{table}{0}                   % new
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}S} % new

\settowidth\rotheadsize{GAP1 (\%) }    % from makecell
    \SetTblrStyle{caption}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Comparison of solution approaches using theoretical instances 
           (values are in average)},
  label = {tab-theo1},
                    ]{
        rowhead = 2,
        colsep  = 3.4pt,
        colspec = {@{} c | *{3}{ccc|} ccc| c | *{3}{ccc|} ccc @{}},
           rows = {font=\small, m},
       row{3-Z} = {rowsep = 0pt}
                    }
\toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}    Instrument?   
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {Mathematical \\ programming}   &   &
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {NA-ACO \\ algorithm}   &   &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {Heuristic \\ algorithm}    &   & 
    & \SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}   GAP1 (\%) 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}   GAP2  (\%)  
            & \SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}  GAP3 (\%) 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{c}    Inst.
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {Mathematical \\ programming}   &   &
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {NA-ACO \\ algorithm}   &   &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {Heuristic \\ algorithm}    &   &
    & \SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}   GAP1 (\%) 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}     GAP2  (\%) 
            & \SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}   GAP3  (\%) \\
    \midrule
    & HPI   & FS\#  & {CPUT \\ (min)}
    & HPI   & FS\#  & {CPUT \\ (min)}
    & HPI   & FS\#  & {CPUT \\ (min)}
    &       &       &                   &
    & HPI   & FS\#  & {CPUT \\ (min)}
    & HPI   & FS\#  & {CPUT \\ (min)}
    & HPI   & FS\#  & {CPUT \\ (min)}
    &       &       &                               \\
    \midrule
%% body of table
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
1   & 1  & 10   & 0.85 & 1  & 10   & 0.03 & 1     & 10   & 0.13 & 0    & 0    & 0.3 
    & 34 & 0.87 & 10  & 7.6 & 0.79 & 10   & 11.73 & 0.97 & 10   & 0.29 & 12.4 & 20.6
    & 2.3 \\
1   & 1  & 10   & 0.85 & 1  & 10   & 0.03 & 1     & 10   & 0.13 & 0    & 0    & 0.3
    & 34 & 0.87 & 10  & 7.6 & 0.79 & 10   & 11.73 & 0.97 & 10   & 0.29 & 12.4 & 20.6
    & 2.3 \\
    \addlinespace
1   & 1  & 10   & 0.85 & 1  & 10   & 0.03 & 1     & 10   & 0.13 & 0    & 0    & 0.3
    & 34 & 0.87 & 10  & 7.6 & 0.79 & 10   & 11.73 & 0.97 & 10   & 0.29 & 12.4 & 20.6
    & 2.3 \\
1   & 1  & 10   & 0.85 & 1  & 10   & 0.03 & 1     & 10   & 0.13 & 0    & 0    & 0.3
    & 34 & 0.87 & 10  & 7.6 & 0.79 & 10   & 11.73 & 0.97 & 10   & 0.29 & 12.4 & 20.6
    & 2.3 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `font=\small` in the `\SetCell` commands? Every cell has `small` font because of `rows={font=\small}`, hasn't it?

Comment: @marv, you may right. I forgot to remove after introduce ``small` to main settings. I will check and correct ASAP. Done!

Answer (score 2):

**Off-topic** Inspired by @Zarko's answer, another idea how you could improve your formatting. I've gotten rid off all vertical lines. Also your table seems to repeat, therefore I reduced it to 13 columns. The resulting table fits into a portrait page and is in my visually pleasing.

[image: table without vertical lines]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}   % new
\usepackage{makecell}   
\usepackage{tabularray} % new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[66]

\begingroup
\setcounter{table}{0}                   % new
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}S} % new

\settowidth\rotheadsize{GAP1 (\%) }    % from makecell
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Comparison of solution approaches using theoretical instances 
        (values are in average)},
    label = {tab-theo1},
    ]{
        rowhead = 2,
        colspec = {@{} *{13}{Q[c,m]} @{}},
        row{1-2} = {font=\small}, row{2} = {belowsep=0pt},
        row{3-Z} = {rowsep = 0pt}, row{3}= {abovesep=4pt}
    }
    \toprule
    \SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}    Instrument?   
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {Mathematical \\ programming}   &   &
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {NA-ACO \\ algorithm}   &   &
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {Heuristic \\ algorithm}    &   & 
    & \SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}   GAP1 (\%) 
    & \SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}   GAP2  (\%)  
    & \SetCell[r=2]{cmd=\rotcell}  GAP3 (\%) \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[lr]{8-10}
    & HPI   & FS\#  & {CPUT \\ (min)}
    & HPI   & FS\#  & {CPUT \\ (min)}
    & HPI   & FS\#  & {CPUT \\ (min)}
    &       &       &                                   \\
    \midrule[leftpos=-1, rightpos=-1]
    %% body of table
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
    1   & 1  & 10   & 0.85 & 1  & 10   & 0.03 & 1     & 10   & 0.13 & 0    & 0    & 0.3 \\
    1   & 1  & 10   & 0.85 & 1  & 10   & 0.03 & 1     & 10   & 0.13 & 0    & 0    & 0.3 \\
    \addlinespace
    1   & 1  & 10   & 0.85 & 1  & 10   & 0.03 & 1     & 10   & 0.13 & 0    & 0    & 0.3 \\
    1   & 1  & 10   & 0.85 & 1  & 10   & 0.03 & 1     & 10   & 0.13 & 0    & 0    & 0.3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup
    
\end{document}
```

You could also consider using `S` type columns from `siunitx` package. They will improve the formatting, if your numbers have different amounts of digits.

Comment: Table is not repeated (as I see),  but trying to be less tall. Is this is sensible is question, with your approach OP will have twice long table as so far and need to rewrite it  ;-). anyway +1 :-)

Comment: I see, just found the 26 columns a bit much :)